# Datagrid getting selected value (delete xml node)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, datagrid

Lets assume there are 2 columns in my datagrid:

```
    <asp:View ID="viewRemove" runat="server">
        <asp:DataGrid ID="dgRemove" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnDeleteCommand="dg_DeleteCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="name" HeaderText="names" />
                <asp:ButtonColumn ButtonType="PushButton" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" ></asp:ButtonColumn>
            </Columns>
        </asp:DataGrid>  
    </asp:View>
```

The first column displays names from a xml file and the button column just hold delete buttons so i can delete the corresponding item to the left of it (1st column).

How exactly can i retrieve/pass this selected value to a function?
In other words when i press the button to the right of the name, it passes the value so i can work with that to remove the corresponding xml node. (using XPath)

```
    XmlDocument XMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XMLDoc.Load(file);
    XPathNavigator nav = XMLDoc.CreateNavigator();

    var node = nav.SelectSingleNode("/root/name['" + ??? + "']");
    node.DeleteSelf();
    XMLDoc.Save(file);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Some Button">
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandArgument='
<# Eval   ("name") %>' >LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to explain a little further if possible? I am not sure what you exactly mean. thanks!

Comment: I'm not used to the default ASP.NET controls because I use DevExpress. So I googled (which you should have done :P) how to pass a parameter to a ButtonColumn and found a forum post which suggested this. This puts a link in the cells and you can also pass a parameter, in this case, the value of the name cell.